# Why do people complain when I call my functions voids?

Tags: programming, c++, faq

I have posted questions about "my void loop" or "my void setup" and people complain that they aren't really voids. But they are! See this example code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);              // wait for a second
}
```

Clearly `setup` and `loop` are voids because they have the word `void` right before them!

---

*Note: this is a reference question.*

Comment: Sorry Nick, but this reference question looks more like a general C++ prgramming question (belonging to StackOverflow then) than an Arduino question, except for the actual functions content. Some members might well vote to close this kind of question as "off topic".

Comment: Yes I realize that, but Arduino users tend to be beginners to programming in general and C++ in particular. The constant references to "the Arduino language" makes me think that they might not consider checking StackOverflow for an answer. Indeed, it is addressing a problem that beginners might not even realize exists (terminology). By posting this Q&A I am attempting to provide a reference point for people who talk about their "void loop" problem.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not insulting people who don't know C++. There was a time when I didn't have the faintest idea about C or C++. Previously I had been using Turbo Pascal, and was used to `procedure` and `function` declarations, and thought that C had very weird syntax. And before Turbo Pascal, well that's a whole other story. :)

Comment: Don't worry Nick, no risk I get you wrong, you are one of my electronics rock stars (I really appreciate your posts about electronics on your site)! I agree with the fact that many Arduino newcomers will first come here for a C++ question. My comment was more about how some Arduino.SE members (including myself) might react on such a question and might consider it off-topic. No hard feelings!

Answer (score 7):

This is an easy mistake for a beginner to C++ to make. Let's look at other languages, like PHP:

```php
function add ($a, $b)
  {
  return $a + $b;
  }
```

Or Lua:

```lua
function add (a, b)
  return a + b
end
```

Or JavaScript:

```js
function add (a, b)
  {
  return a + b;
  }
```

Or VBscript:

```vbscript
Function add (a, b)
  add = a + b
End Function
```

All those languages have the word "function" there to indicate that you are declaring a function.

---

So what does C++ look like:

```c++
int add (int a, int b)
  {
  return a + b;
  }
```

So this must be an "int" right? Or what if it doesn't return a value?

```
void loop ()
  {
  }
```

Now it's a "void"? Kind of a weird name for a function!

Actually `int` and `void` in these examples are not weird names for functions. They are the **return types** of those functions. `int add (int a, int b)` is a **function** that returns an int. And `void loop ()` is a **function** that returns nothing.

The C++ compiler can deduce when it is seeing a function declaration from some clues:

- A return type (eg. int, float, long)
- A name (the function name)
- Some parentheses (for the function arguments)

Think of the word `function` as being there in spirit:

```
int [function] add (int a, int b)
    ^^^^^^^^^^   <-- don't actually type this!
    {
    return a + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a phrase like " my int a or my CustomType a " people would interpret those phrases to mean that you have a variable `a` that is an instance of an `int` or a `CustomType`.

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types you can't have an object or reference of type `void`.

If you have a phrase like "my void setup", I think most people would try to read that as implying you have a variable `setup` of type `void`, which I don't think makes sense, to most people.

What you actually have is this:

```
void setup() {
...
}
```

I think most people would phrase this as "my function setup, which takes no arguments are returns nothing".

Comment: you missed the "Note"?

Comment: I guess I did,  and I later noticed that the same person answered it as asked it, which seemed weird.  I have never seen or heard of such a thing as a "reference question, at least not on stackoverflow,  is it documented somewhere?  I searched the meta site and did not find it.

Comment: See [Can I answer my own question?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). From that: **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged.***

Comment: Thanks,  I guess I have seen cases were people answer their own question, _after_ the find a solution, but not this type of case.  I can see cases were it would be a value add.   But I guess then I don't see the point of someone pointing out the fact that it is a "reference" question, after all a question is a question and someone could still have a better answer than the person that asked it.